# Disabling BIOS error without graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, bios

I've recently inherited an old HP M7000, and decided to make a headless server out of it. My only problem is, that the included motherboard (Asus P5LP-LE) does not have an integrated graphics card, and the only one at my disposal is a bit too powerful to be in a server (Radeon HD3870).

Given that I want to make it use the least possible power, I want to get rid of the graphics card, but any time I try, the computer won't boot, and I found no option to disable this behavior. Does anyone know a way to bypass this error some way? I would prefer an answer not beginning, ending with, or containing "buy a cheap graphics card"!

Comment: Are you sure that there is no integrated graphics? [This HP spec page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c00864946#N55) and [this third party page](http://www.ascendtech.us/asus-p5lp-le-945g-1066fsb-ddr2-sata-pcie_i_mb4asup5lpleul8.aspx) seem to disagree. 
Both claim that there is an Intel [GMA950](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA) which you [can enable in the BIOS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfiEvUgri1c).

I assume that temporarily using the Radeon 3870 to change BIOS settings is not a problem.

Comment: Youtube seems to be acting up again. (I only got it to work after disabling a few ad- and tracking blockers). So here is a screenshot of rather than the youtube link. [http://i.stack.imgur.com/6SG3U.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6SG3U.png)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The motherboard is not the Leonite release you linked (I wish it was), but the Lithium. Key differences: Lithium has no integrated graphics, but has a PCI Expansion slot.
There's detailed information on the [HP Site](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c00379616).
I did try enabling it there, but the only option it gives me is either PCI, or PCI-E.

Comment: In that case I am stuck with 1) Update the BIOS and hope the newer one boots without a graphical card. 2) The answer which you do not prefer. or 3) Use a 'real' server. (And yes, I do realise that if 2 is not an option, then 3 most likely is not an option either). But for completeness sake...

Comment: I am already on the latest BIOS so it does not help. Apparently it is time to get the spare cash, and visit some second-hand electronics store for a cheap used PCI VGA.

Comment: If you haven't already, check your CMOS setup screens for "halt on error" conditions -- if you can disable that for "display" (as you frequently can for "keyboard"), that may let you do what you want.  Alternately, an eBay cheapy VGA card should only consume 10 watts or so and you may be able to set the server OS to turn off the graphics as soon as it's started, so the VGA would consume even less.

Comment: Well the thing is, that server has been already discarded, and replaced by a HP Microserver. It was solved later by using a small PCI-E graphics card that I found inbetween the stuff the original computer came with (like, three boxes of electronics stuff).